# Add description to the fields in newform.aspx and editform.aspx?

Tags: list, form

What's the best way to add a description to the fields?

e.g. I have a field called `Location` and I want to put description below it about how to enter data for it. I know I can customize these forms in SharePoint Designer and achieve this, but is there any other good way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply fill in the Description field on the column's definition in List Settings. The Description is automatically displayed if it exists.

M.

Comment: I don't want to fill description field...I guess I am confusing when i say description i mean just some note below any field I am showing in list describing how to fill the data....

Comment: Well, the Description field can contain anything, really.  Is there any reason not to use it?

Comment: You mean to say that If i have four fields below which I want to add some note like

Location
(First Letter should be capital)

Name
(ALL Capital) and so on...

So i should use description field? thats what you are suggesting...

Comment: Yes, you've got it.  Just try adding something into the Description for a column and then go see where it's added on the form.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Marc.

But in case description is not enough, you could [customize a list form with SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101191111033.aspx).

Comment: And +1 for Toni. Of course, customizing the list form is perhaps going a litte far for just this requirement.  It does, however, let you do almost anything you can think of.

Comment: Thanks for replying but as I said I don't wanna use Designer here for customizing .....

Comment: You can't have it both ways.  Either you can use the OTB functionality for showing a description or you have to add some form of a customization.  If SharePoint designer isn't an option then you can build custom forms that are deployed as a solution.  The cost would be very high for very little value.

Comment: @STS.PS: Sorry I did not see that part :(((, however these are the only two options. You can also upgrade to SharePoint 2010 and customize forms with InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following feature to be really useful.  It adds a new link to the list settings page called 'form settings'.  This allows you to customise whether descriptions show on the form and where.

It can be very useful.

http://officetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/15713